How do I prevent a DB user to change table contents in SQL Server?
How do I specify that a DB user cannot edit the AspNetUserRoles table in SQL Server? Currently, the user has Membership->db_owner permission, and it can do everything.
I would like to control permissions only manually from SQL Server admin user.
EDIT: with 'edit' I'm referring to adding a row in the table.

Don't give them the db_owner role. Owners can do anything.

throw away db_owner permission and set a role with exactly what you need
CREATE ROLE myspecialrole;  
GRANT SELECT ON schema :: [dbo] TO myspecialrole;
GRANT INSERT ON schema :: [dbo] TO myspecialrole;
GRANT UPDATE ON schema :: [dbo] TO myspecialrole;
GRANT EXECUTE ON schema :: [dbo] TO myspecialrole;
DENY INSERT ON dbo.AspNetUserRoles TO myspecialrole;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'myspecialrole', 'User';
EXEC sp_droprolemember N'db_owner', 'User';
GO


We have a large number of tables, should I repeat the code above for each one? Could I do the opposite? Everything open, then close something?

@abenci Usually schemas are a good way to control a large number of related objects. You can then apply permissions to a whole schema of objects instead of individually to each object. That's what MBuschi's code above actually does, but they're doing it to the default dbo schema for all of the GRANTs, and then it explicitly DENYs the one table you don't want inserted into. So long story short, it does what you want.

This code will do it.
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.AspNetUserRoles TO [Dbuser]
GO
DENY INSERT ON dbo.AspNetUserRoles TO [Dbuser]
GO

Details about deny syntax.
Complete test code here:
--Create a test database
CREATE DATABASE [permissiontest]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'permissiontest', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\permissiontest.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'permissiontest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\permissiontest_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH LEDGER = OFF
GO

--Create a login
CREATE LOGIN [aspentuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'rX/u5r+imKFPRfFBVzyon3YIgTg9G6i0D1ZsXGZN7Qk=', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

--Create a user and make it a member of db_owner
USE [permissiontest]
GO
CREATE USER [aspentuser] FOR LOGIN [aspentuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [aspentuser] 
GO

--Creating a table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [a] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   [b] [int] NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [a] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Inserting test data
INSERT INTO dbo.AspNetUserRoles
(
  b
)
VALUES
(100),(200), (300);
GO

--Denying update permission for one table 
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.AspNetUserRoles TO aspentuser
GO

--Executing as the test user
EXECUTE AS USER = 'aspentuser'
GO

--SELECT will succeed
SELECT 
  [a],[b]
FROM    dbo.AspNetUserRoles
GO

--INSERT and UPDATE will fail
UPDATE dbo.AspNetUserRoles
SET [b] = 500
WHERE [a] = 1;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.AspNetUserRoles
(
  b
)
VALUES
(500);
GO

REVERT
GO


If the user is a db_owner, they can edit their own permissions, so this won't stop a determined bad actor.  Also, should expand to include deny on insert and delete, depending on how broad a definition OP meant when they said "edit"



The user is defined at the SQL Server level, and it connects to the DB from the website only. How could one of the programmers change its permissions if he/she does not have access to SQL Server?


I'm referring specifically to adding a row in the table.



Can you please modify your question and add all the details there? I modified the answer to prevent insert.

@abenci "1) The user is defined at the SQL Server level, and it connects to the DB from the website only. How could one of the programmers change its permissions if he/she does not have access to SQL Server?" - What stops one of the programmers from downloading SSMS and logging into the server as that user? The user itself is able to modify its own permissions since it's in the db_owner role.

Good point, so what can I do? "throw away db_owner permission and set a role with exactly what you need" as in the other answer?

@abenci Yes, pretty much. You should only provision what is the minimal needed permissions. This is a standard security ideology.
